# Extra svg and text from PDF in python

Tags: python, pdf, pymupdf

I need to get text and svgs incorporated in pdf in python. I tried PyDF2, PyPDF4, tika did not work. I tried using pymupdf but getting below error. Can some help me with it.
I am using python 3.8, pycharm. All modules required for pymupdf are already there.

**Error :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/PDFImage.py", line 2, in <module>
    doc = fitz.open("./Docs/pdffile.pdf")
AttributeError: module 'fitz' has no attribute 'open'
```

Comment: Does anything from here help?: https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/660

Comment: I checked that but could not understand. What does "this error usually indicates that __init__.py wasn't executed. Which e.g. happens when you are in the installation fitz directory and start python." mean.

Comment: What's after the "e.g." is just an example of why a file with the path `fitz/__init__.py` wasn't executed. The particular example might not apply to you. What might apply is this [comment](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/660#issuecomment-694845403), where it's revealed that the error came from a broken installation of PyMuPDF.

Comment: I did the re installation as well but that too did not fix the problem. Do anyone know the stable version of pymupdf that i can install.

Comment: For the latest stable version, go to pypi.org and search for "PyMuPDF" (without the quotes). That said, it would help a *lot* if you described the steps that you used to install PyMuPDF.